# How to solve Illuminate\Database\QueryException error?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

After the login page, this error appears, that is on the page where the list of shows should be.

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= and `pending_tickets`.`status` = = where exists (select * from `showtimes` whe' at line 1 (SQL: select `shows`.* from `shows` inner join `showtimes` on `showtimes`.`show_id` = `shows`.`id` inner join `venues` on `venues`.`id` = `shows`.`venue_id` inner join `timezones` on `timezones`.`id` = `venues`.`timezone_id` left join `tickets` on `tickets`.`showtime_id` = `showtimes`.`id` left join `shows_venue_exclusions` on `shows_venue_exclusions`.`show_id` = `shows`.`id` left join tickets as pending_tickets on `pending_tickets`.`showtime_id` = `showtimes`.`id` and `pending_tickets`.`user_id` = = and `pending_tickets`.`status` = = where exists (select * from `showtimes` where `shows`.`id` = `showtimes`.`show_id` and `showtimes`.`date_time` is not null and `showtimes`.`auto_send_date_time` is not null and `showtimes`.`max_person` > 0 and `showtimes`.`online` = 1 and ((`tickets`.`id` is not null and tickets.showtime_id = showtimes.id and `tickets`.`held_seat` = 0 and `tickets`.`status` = available) or (`showtimes`.`disappear_when_sold_out` = 0 and (`tickets`.`held_seat` != 0 or `tickets`.`status` != available)) or (`pending_tickets`.`id` is not null and `pending_tickets`.`user_id` = 2 and `pending_tickets`.`status` = pending)) and `showtimes`.`date_time` is not null and CONVERT_TZ(showtimes.auto_send_date_time, timezones.timezone_id, 'UTC') > '2022-11-17 04:56:59') and `archived` = 0 group by `shows`.`id` order by `created_at` desc limit 10 offset 0) (View: D:\Projects\audience-services\resources\views\shows\shows.blade.php)

I tried updating the database, downloading different dumps, but this error still appears. By the way, there is no such problem on mac. This error only appears on a Windows laptop.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this exact error, but in my case I was binding values for the **LIMIT** clause without specifying the type. I'm just dropping this here in case somebody gets this error for the same reason. Without specifying the type **LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset;** resulted in **LIMIT '10' OFFSET '1';** instead of **LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1;.** What helps to correct that is the following:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':limit', intval($limit, 10), \PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':offset', intval($offset, 10), \PDO::PARAM_INT);
```